# Get theme name of combobox item on pyqt5

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt5, qt-designer

I would like to get theme name entered in QT designer of the item of a combobox entered like this into Qt5-tools designer:
[image]

I have try this code:

```
def load_actions_tips(self):
    combo = self.form.converter_action_choice
    for i in range(combo.count()):
        print(f"{combo.itemText(i) = }")
        print(f"{combo.itemData(i) = }")
        print(f"{combo.itemIcon(i).themeName = }")
        print(f"{combo.itemIcon(i).themeName.__name__ = }")
        print(f"{combo.itemIcon(i).themeName.__qualname__ = }")
        print(f"{combo.itemIcon(i).themeName.__repr__ = }")
        print(f"{combo.itemIcon(i).themeName.__str__ = }")
        print(f"{combo.itemIcon(i).themeName.__text_signature__ = }")
        print(f"{str(combo.itemIcon(i).themeName) = }")
        print(f"{dir(combo.itemIcon(i).themeName) = }")
```

The goal of this is to add the theme name to the item value of the combobox automatically in order to permit someone to add 'tooltips' of an item of a combobox from QT designer as described [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/pyqt5-setting-different-tooltip-to-different-item-of-combobox/).

The goal here is to get the variable equal to 'blablo' for the selected item.

Comment: The [`themeName`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qicon.html#themeName) is *the name of the current icon theme*, not what you typed in Designer. That **could** be available through [`name()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qicon.html#name), as long as the icon is found *and* the icon engine properly supports it: so, even if you set that name in Designer, it's still possible that you cannot get it back programmatically.

Comment: `combo.itemIcon(i).name()` is returning `''`

Comment: That's exactly what I said, you cannot rely on it. If you want to set custom data, you have to do it programmatically.

Comment: @VincentBénet Your screenshot from Qt Designer clearly shows that the icon theme-name is *not set*. If it was, the actual icon itself would be shown beside its name in the Property Editor. This proves there is no such "blablo" icon included in the current icon theme on your system. To undertsand what the names actually mean and how to use them properly, see [the docs for QIcon.fromTheme](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qicon.html#fromTheme). TLDR: the names aren't just random text, so you can't hack them for use as tooltips (or whatever).